# Will the Czech borders be open with the expiry of the state of emergency?

Tags: czech-republic, covid-19

According to the [statement of the Czech Ministry of Interior](https://www.vlada.cz/cz/media-centrum/aktualne/vyhlaseni-nouzoveho-stavu-180234/#cestovani_od_11_kvetna), the borders of Czechia are closed **for foreigners for the duration of the state of emergency**. The state of emergency is **valid until May 17th**. Does this mean that on May the 18th any EU citizen will be able to enter the country? I see a lot of conflicting information in the [news](https://www.novinky.cz/zahranicni/evropa/clanek/viden-budeme-jednat-o-otevreni-hranic-s-ceskem-40323397). Also, it is not possible to book train tickets for any date after the 17th.

Comment: No one knows the future. The Czech government might allow the border closure order to expire, or the government might extend or change the order. Other governments have both ended, and extended, closures. I vote to close as opinion-based.

Comment: I am not convinced there is anything wrong with the question: it's interesting to know what the legal consequence would be and whether the Czech government announced any plan to let the measure expire. But do note that May 17th is 4 days from now, that's typically plenty of time to declare or extend a state of emergency.

Comment: @Relaxed The question asks about what the status will be at a future time. Decisions like these are politically-made, "informed" by both political and medical opinion. Both can change before the question's target date, and we've all seen a lot of governmental backs-and-forths in this Covid-19 experience. Thus, it seems to me impossible to predict with certainty. One can opine...but that'd be opinion-based, wouldn't it?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Just about everything that's being discussed here is liable to change and Covid-19 makes things more volatile than usual but it doesn't make sense to consider that asking about the future makes a question inherently unanswerable. Otherwise we would never write about transportation schedules or visas. What's being asked is not your personal prediction but whatever information is available from official or reliable sources. A qualified or probabilistic prediction is not inherently more opinion-based. And even if a plan is conditional or tentative, it's not an opinion.

Comment: For political reasons, the Czech government currently doesn't intend to formally extend the state of emergency. Instead, they're trying to emulate it by reimplementing the restrictions using new special legislation. So a reasonable assumption might be that they will succeed in this effort and the restrictions will stand even after the state of emergency expires, but that's just a guess. Unless someone from the government chimes in here, it's IMHO impossible to answer this question with certainty.